# Compare strings independently of current language

Tags: android

i'm having a hard time trying to understand how to deal with language - and trying to explain myself in english.

For example, take a look at this

```
<resources>
<string name="temperature_celsius">Celsius</string>
<string name="temperature_fahrenheit">Fahrenheit</string>
<string name="temperature_kelvin">Kelvin</string>

<string-array name="temperature">
    <item>@string/temperature_celsius</item>
    <item>@string/temperature_fahrenheit</item>
    <item>@string/temperature_kelvin</item>
</string-array>
</resources>
```

Now, imagine that i have another xml file where Celsius, Fahrenheit and Kelvin are written differently in another language.

```
//name of temperature units in another galaxy
<resources>
<string name="temperature_celsius">Celsioso</string>
<string name="temperature_fahrenheit">Fahrenheitzkeum</string>
<string name="temperature_kelvin">Kalvon</string>

<string-array name="temperature">
    <item>@string/temperature_celsius</item>
    <item>@string/temperature_fahrenheit</item>
    <item>@string/temperature_kelvin</item>
</string-array>
```

Now, i want my alien user to see the units in its own language, so i need to compare them taken that into account. Is there an efficient way in which i could do this instead of hardcoding the value of each string item? I tried using a switch but it says **constant expression required**, i think it works if i use if-else, but it looks ugly:

```
//convert from celsius(baseUnit) to something else(endUnit) 
//baseUnit and endUnit are strings taken from two autocompletetextviews
if(baseUnit.equals(mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.temperature_celsius))) {
        convertFromCelsius(endUnit, inputValue, mContext);
```

I'm handling the UI in my main activity, the job of converting each unit is done in other java classes (that's why i'm using a mContext).

Thanks, and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Just in case anyone is wondering, the only way I found to resolve this is using a lots of if-else. It really does make the code uglier, but comparing them by position in the array is a mess, and apparently you can't use switch to compare strings generated in xml.